# Recalculating the "state" of 50 objects every second

Tags: c#

I want to recalculate "StrategyState" of some object every second. I do not want to create a Timer for that, because at the same time, from another thread, I can access "StrategyState" property (also, Timer probably would be too heavy for my simple problem). I defined StrategyState type myself this way:

```
public enum StrategyState
{
    OnlyKill,
    Working,
    ClosingStage1,
    ClosingStage2,
    Closed
}
```

I'm not sure if it will be "thread-safe" to write such object from one thread and to read from another thread.

So I was thinking to "lazy-update" my `StrategyState State` field, like that:

```
....
if ( /* State was not updated for one second or more. */ ) {
    RecalculateState()
}
switch (State) {
    .... // Work
```

How do I test state was not updated for one second or more without adding too much latency?

I can obviously create Stopwatch, but note that I need to update about 50 states totally for different objects in different threads. I'm not sure if I should add 50 Stopwatch to the system.
Probably, it's better to add one Stopwatch and share it, because I guess Stopwatch class is likely thread-safe.

What can you suggest?

Comment: What do you have against `Timer`? `System.Threading.Timer` would be fine for this. Throw in some locking around the getter and setter and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've implemented it like this:

```
private long recalculateStateTimestamp;
private const long oneSecond = 10000000;

.....
long newTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
if (newTime - recalculateStateTimestamp < oneSecond)
{
    return;
}
recalculateStateTimestamp = newTime;
```

I assume this is one of the fastest ways to implement it. Also, it is partly thread-safe (enough for me).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `DateTime` for the last evaluation time:

```
private DateTime m_lastStateEvaluation = DateTime.MinValue;
```

And then

```
if ((DateTime.Now - m_lastStateEvaluation).TotalSeconds >= 1))
{ 
    // Evaluate state
    m_lastStateEvaluation = DateTime.Now;
}
```

This won't add too much time at all to the operation.

Incidentally, using a `lock` statement will resolve any threading issues if you use a timer. And you could have a single timer handle all 50 objects if you want.